# How to define a singleton set?

Tags: agda

Assume I have a value `x : A` and I want to define a set containing only `x`.

This is what I tried:

```
open import Data.Product
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

-- Singleton x is the set that only contains x. Its values are tuples containing
-- a value of type A and a proof that this value is equal to x.
Singleton : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} → (x : A) → Set ℓ
Singleton {A = A} x = Σ[ y ∈ A ] (y ≡ x)

-- injection
singleton : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} → (x : A) → Singleton x
singleton x = x , refl

-- projection
fromSingleton : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} {x : A} → Singleton x → A
fromSingleton s = proj₁ s
```

Is there a better way to do it?

---

An example for why I want this: If you have a monoid over some set A, then you can form a category with A as the only object. To express that in Agda you need a way to write "the set containing only A".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a very good way to do it. Usually, when you want to create a "subset" of a type, it looks like:

```
postulate
  A : Set
  P : A → Set

record Subset : Set where
  field
    value : A
    prop  : P value
```

However, this might not be a subset in the sense that it can actually contain more elements than the original type. That is because `prop` might have more propositionally different values. For example:

```
open import Data.Nat

data ℕ-prop : ℕ → Set where
  c1 : ∀ n → ℕ-prop n
  c2 : ∀ n → ℕ-prop n

record ℕ-Subset : Set where
  field
    value : ℕ
    prop  : ℕ-prop value
```

And suddenly, the subset has twice as many elements as the original type. This example is a bit contrived, I agree, but imagine you had a subset relation on sets (sets from set theory). Something like this is actually fairly possible:

```
sub₁ : {1, 2} ⊆ {1, 2, 3, 4}
sub₁ = drop 3 (drop 4 same)

sub₂ : {1, 2} ⊆ {1, 2, 3, 4}
sub₂ = drop 4 (drop 3 same)
```

---

The usual approach to this problem is to use irrelevant arguments:

```
record Subset : Set where
  field
    value : A
    .prop : P value
```

This means that two values of type `Subset` are equal if they have the same `value`, the `prop` field is *irrelevant* to the equality. And indeed:

```
record Subset : Set where
  constructor sub
  field
    value : A
    .prop : P value

prop-irr : ∀ {a b} {p : P a} {q : P b} →
  a ≡ b → sub a p ≡ sub b q
prop-irr refl = refl
```

---

However, this is more of a guideline, because your representation doesn't suffer from this problem. This is because the implementation of pattern matching in Agda implies *axiom K*:

```
K : ∀ {a p} {A : Set a} (x : A) (P : x ≡ x → Set p) (h : x ≡ x) →
  P refl → P h
K x P refl p = p
```

Well, this doesn't tell you much. Luckily, there's another property that is equivalent to axiom K:

```
uip : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} {x y : A} (p q : x ≡ y) → p ≡ q
uip refl refl = refl
```

This tells us that there's only one way in which two elements can be equal, namely `refl` (`uip` means *uniqueness of identity proofs*).

This means that when you use propositional equality to make a subset, you're getting a true subset.

---

Let's make this explicit:

```
isSingleton : ∀ {ℓ} → Set ℓ → Set _
isSingleton A = Σ[ x ∈ A ] (∀ y → x ≡ y)
```

`isSingleton A` expresses the fact that `A` contains only one element, up to propositonal equality. And indeed, `Singleton x` is a singleton:

```
Singleton-isSingleton : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} (x : A) →
  isSingleton (Singleton x)
Singleton-isSingleton x = (x , refl) , λ {(.x , refl) → refl}
```

Interestingly, this also works without axiom K. If you put `{-# OPTIONS --without-K #-}` pragma at the top of your file, it will still compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a record without projections:

```
record Singleton {α} {A : Set α} (x : A) : Set α where

fromSingleton : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} {x : A} -> Singleton x -> A
fromSingleton {x = x} _ = x

singleton : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> (x : A) -> Singleton x
singleton _ = _
```

Or equalently

```
record Singleton {α} {A : Set α} (x : A) : Set α where

  fromSingleton = x
open Singleton public

singleton : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> (x : A) -> Singleton x
singleton _ = _
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Nat

f : Singleton 5 -> ℕ
f x = fromSingleton x

test : f (singleton 5) ≡ 5
test = refl

test' : f _ ≡ 5
test' = refl
```

And this is rejected:

```
fail : f (singleton 4) ≡ 4
fail = ?
```

The error:

```
4 != 5 of type ℕ
when checking that the expression singleton 4 has type Singleton 5
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be defined as an [*indexed* datatype](http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.3/language/data-types.html#indexed-datatypes):

```
data Singleton {ℓ : _} {A : Set ℓ} : A -> Set where
  singleton : (a : A) -> Singleton a
```

This is analogous to how propositional equality `a ≡ b` is indexed by two particular elements `a` and `b`, or how `Vector X n` is indexed by a particular `n ∈ ℕ`.